# Matlab/Simulink: Convert Data Table (Measured) Into Lookup Table

Tags: matlab

I have simulated a magnetic system and I have 2 input variables and 1 output variable. The result looks like this:

```
myData = [...
0 0 1.1;...
0 1 1.2;...
0 2 1.2;...
1 0.1 2.1;...
1 0.9 2.2;...
1 2.05 2.2;...   
3 0.1 3.1;...
3 1.2 3.2;...
3 1.9 3.2;...    
];
```

Column 1 and 2 are the input values. Column 3 is the output variable:

```
x = myData(:,1);
y = myData(:,2);
z = myData(:,3);
```

I want to create a 2D lookup table in Simulink with `x` and `y` as inputs and `z` as an output. I do not get how to do this. It would be easy if the 2nd input variable would be evenly spaced like here:

```
x = [0 1 2];
y = [0 1 2];
z = [0 0 0; 1 2 3; 4 4 8]
```

In the Simulink lookup table block you would put:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**In a nutshell:**
How do I treat my data do be able to use a lookup table in Simulink?

Comment: Damn. I made a typo in the title. Can anyone edit it?

Comment: No problem. FYI, you can always edit your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

The matlab/simulink command you are looking for is set_param.

The matlab command you are looking for in mat2str

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not think that you understand my question or maybe I wasn't clear enough. Anyway -- the question in unanswered for about two years :).

Comment: I think i understood it well. Combine the two functions and you have your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set.
x = [0 1 2];
y = [0 1 2];
Then interpolate z corresponding to x and y, using the raw data available. This will form an evenly spaced LUT.